# Is there a restriction on the number of Entity values in Watson Conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

We want to have an entity to identify a part number in the user's question, and we have around 4k to 5k part numbers, is there any restriction on the number of entities that we can put in Watson Conversation service.

I tried to put 1000 values for an entity, and the Conversation tool started to freeze.

Is there a good way to configure huge number of values in an entity, so that Conversation can identify them.

Answer (score 2):

Entity limits are detailed here:

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/entities.html#entity-limits

Currently as I write it is the following:

```
Service plan      | Entities per workspace | Entity values per workspace | Entity synonyms per workspace
Standard/ Premium | 1000                   | 100,000                     | 100,000
             Lite | 25                     | 100,000                     | 100,000
```

--

However if you have fixed structure in your part numbers, you can look for that instead and use your application layer to verify.

For example, if your part number is XYZ00001 then you can do something like the following for the matching condition.

```
input.text.matches('$.*?[A-Z]{3}\d{5}.*?$')
```

Then if you wanted to capture the value, you would used the `extract` as follows.

```
{
  "context": { 
    "serial_number": "<? input.text.extract('$.*?([A-Z]{3}\\d{5}).*?$',1) ?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Serial is $serial_number"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Even though they say the limit is 100,000 values per entity, the tool freezes at 1k values. We were planning to use extract method, part numbers are a mix of numbers and letters, we tried regex, but could not find a regex that works in conversation.

Comment: The limit refers to the engine, not the tooling. You can build your own workspace with the Workspace API.

Comment: Mixed numbers and letters as part of a part number is fine, as long as at least one part of the pattern prevents you picking up a word.